# What is the lambda equivalent of this query

Tags: c#, lambda

Suppose In `SQL` I am trying to run this query

```
Select * from MyTable where SomeCondition=true
```

I am currently using this lambda expression for the above query

```
using(var db=new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
var result=db.MyTable.Where(myTable=>myTable.SomeCondition.Equals(true)).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Is this the correct way or should I do something like this

```
using(var db=new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
    var result=db.MyTable.Where(myTable=>myTable.SomeCondition.Equals(true)).Select(myTable=>myTable).SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Can anyone suggest me a correct way to do such type of queries in `Lambda`?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Looks fine, I would probably do: .Where(t => t.SomeCondition == true)

Comment: I would probably do: .Where(t => t.SomeCondition).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: `== true` is not necessary. if `SomeCondition` is a boolean and true, you don't need to compare it to true to get a result.

Comment: Why do you use `SingleOrDefault` which throws an exception if there are multiple rows? You sql returns all rows.

Comment: SteenT So I think what you suggest is fine.Thanks.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think I should use FirstOrDefault instead , is it ?

Comment: @Femaref ok I got it that means t.SomeCondition should be enought.Thanks.

Comment: @freebird: If you want only the first record(if any) instead of all, yes.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am trying to findout whether there is any record in the table that is satisfying my condition.So do you think I should use FirstOrDefault().Thanks.

Comment: So you want a boolean in the end? Or do you want a record satisfying your condition to be returned? If it's the former, you can do away with `.Where()` and just use `.Any()` with the same lambda expression. That will return a boolean if your condition is satisfied.

Comment: @rikitikitik Not a bad idea , I just want to check if any record matching my condition exists.I think Any() is good as well.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking if this part is necessary?

```
.Select(myTable=>myTable)
```

The answer is no. It turns a list of items into a list of the same items. The lambda:

```
x => x
```

Is the "identity function", returning exactly what it is passed.

**NB**

Some other answers are advising `FirstOrDefault` as an alternative to `SingleOrDefault`. If the query may return multiple records, and you have no `OrderBy` clause, then the database may return results in random order. So using `FirstOrDefault` is like saying "pick one at random".

That may be okay if all the records are "good enough" (in some sense). If not, you should add an `OrderBy` clause so that the first record is the "best" record. Or perhaps you want to perform the action on *every* record that matches your condition, in which case use neither `FirstOrDefault` nor SingleOrDefault`. Just loop through the results.

Finally (based on comments below) if you just want to know if there is a record that matches, but you don't want to examine its contents, use `Any`.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input , basically I just want to check if there is any record that matches my condition , so FirstOrDefault() might help.I was also thinking why not use .Any() which will server my purpose.Your comments on this?

Comment: If you don't want to examine the contents of the matching record then `Any` is good, it just returns a bool (and you can pass it the predicate that you want any record to satisfy). Behind the scenes the database layer will usually turn it into a `SQL COUNT`.

Comment: Exactly I just want to know if the record exists I dont want to examine contents of the records , so I think Any() is good in my case.Can you just update the answer I will accept it.Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you're *just* filtering, performing an identity transformation, then using `SingleOrDefault`, you can do that all with the [overload of `SingleOrDefault` which takes a predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534956):

```
using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    var result = db.MyTable.SingleOrDefault(myTable => myTable.SomeCondition);
    // Use result...
}
```

(You can use `FirstOrDefault` here instead, if that's better.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.Ya I think FirstOrDefault() should be better in this case as I think there can be many records matching the condition.

Comment: I am using this right now var result = db.MyTable.SingleOrDefault(myTable => myTable.SomeCondition);

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way:

using(var db=new DataClasses1DataContext())

{

```
var result=db.MyTable.Where(x=>x.SomeCondition.Equals(true));

}
```

Now you will get the result

Comment: No need to check .Equals(True) just left only SomeCondition

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need the select if you don't want to project the table:

```
using(var db=new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    var result=db.MyTable.Where(myTable => myTable.SomeCondition);
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't take into account the `SingleOrDefault` part.

Answer (score 1):

No need to add below code at end of the statement.

```
SingleOrDefault()
```

Use the following code for that.

```
using(var db=new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    var result=db.MyTable.Where(myTable=>myTable.SomeCondition);
}
```